# Null pointer exception is displayed while trying to replay Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to replay my JMeter script where i am clicking on few buttons to navigate between[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JTxI.png) webpages. But i am getting null pointer exception in the response data section. Strange part is that under the sampler result section i am getting response code as '200'. I was using "Test script recorder" while capturing the requests. With the previous builds i followed the same approach but never faced the issue.

The exception reads like:

{"errorTrace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat com.bird.common.service.NewReportService.getSchemaDetails(NewReportService.java:97)\r\n\tat com.bird.common.controller.NewReportController.getSchemaDetails(NewReportController.java:197)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:178)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:444)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:432)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:84)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\n","errorCode":"ERR-9026","error":"Unknown Exception. Please Contact Support Team"}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to load test a web application with [Spring Session Management](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-session) enabled. It means that you will not be able to replay the recorded script "as is" without applying [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) to it.

1. Record your script one more time
2. Compare 2 resulting .jmx scripts and identify the differences
3. Inspect **previous** page response to locate the dynamic element, extract it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using a suitable [JMeter PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replace recorded hard-coded value with the relevant variable

In most common setups it is enough to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan to automatically handle cookies and [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send the relevant session header value which can be obtained from the cookie, however implementation might be different. You need to reach out to your web application developers to learn more about the details.

Comment: Yes you were right,but can you tell me why Jmeter shows the response in green color & the response code as 200 when the response is actually failing. Also what is the best way to compare two jmx files or manual check is the only way? I there any trick that i can apply while debugging the failure in jmeter script as sometimes it is very difficult to understand the issue why it failed.

Comment: Because JMeter automatically treats [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) **below 400** as successful. If you need to check presence of the expected page or absence or error messages you need to add i.e. [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) to the request and define your pass/fail criteria there.

Comment: I am able to correlate the values now. But i am facing another issue where my script is running for 15 mins & still going on even though i have limited the running time as 4 mins. So my loop count is forever but the scheduler value is set as 240 sec. From the view results in tree i can see the requests have stopped but from Perfmon i can see threads are still running. What can be the reason for this & any resolution that you think appropriate.